# Create 1 mp3 file out of several mp3 files some with a different tempo, a pause between each mp3 files and a background music

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to create 1 mp3 file containing:

1. mp3 file 1 (playing at tempo 0.7)
2. a 1 second pause
3. mp3 file 2 (playing at tempo 1)
4. a 1 second pause
5. mp3 file 3 (playing at tempo 0.8)
6. create the mp3 file based on the above request.
   NOTE: a background music will be played during the whole duration of the created mp3

Anyone know if it is possible and how to do that in 1 command?

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! We are not a free coding service but a community of people interested in computers that are willing to share their knowledge and experience. If you have already tried something, please post it here, otherwise this question is likely to be closed.

Comment: Hi, I tried using -i and concat for filter_complex and apad for the pauses